# Puppet on windows is extremely slow

Tags: puppet

Windows 7, installed puppet via chocolatey. Running "Start Command Prompt with Puppet", and then creating an EMPTY file "tennessee.pp", and then invoking within the prompt

```
puppet apply -v --debug --evaltrace --noop tennessee.pp
```

Just sits doing absolutely nothing. I'm not sure what other debug flags I could hand it. It's just dead quiet. Ctrl+C a few times results in

```
Exiting
Exiting
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

How can I possibly get puppet to give me some more information on what it's doing? I wish I had more information to share, but again, no output whatsoever.

Comment: `EMPTY file ... Just sits doing absolutely nothing`. Uhm put something **in the file**?  I have never used an empty file, I would not expect trying to apply any empty file would do anything useful at all.