# Puppet Apply on Windows more than 28 times slower since version 3.3

Tags: windows-7, puppet

**Problem**

Puppet on Windows has been upgraded from 2.7.22 to 3.5.1 on Windows7.
When `puppet apply` was executed it looked like puppet was stuck. A retry demonstrated the same behavior and the run finished after minutes, while puppet indicated that the run took `0.17 seconds`. Neither a bug regarding slow performance of Puppet on Windows nor identical questions including time analysis were found. [One related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/543701/puppet-on-windows-is-extremely-slow) was found.

**Analysis**

An identical puppet apply (`puppet apply "C:\temp\puppettest\site.pp"`) was executed using several [Puppet on Windows versions](https://downloads.puppetlabs.com/windows/). The results are as follows:

- 2.7.23: X < 10s
- 3.0.2:  X < 15s
- 3.1.1:  X < 15s
- 3.2.4:  X < 15s
- 3.3.2:  X > 420s
- 3.4.3:  X > 420s
- 3.5.1:  X > 420s

**Outcome**

Puppet Apply on Windows more than 28 times (420/15) slower since version 3.3

**Question**

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Does `--debug` provide any info on what it's doing during that time?

Comment: `puppet apply --debug "C:\temp\puppettest\site.pp"` does not show any debug information. The cursor flashes until the puppet run has been finished.

Comment: How about with `--verbose` as well?

Comment: When the puppet run finished it showed more information thanks to the --debug option. I will add --verbose as well and post the output.

Comment: In the past when I used Puppet on Windows 2.7.22 the effect of -d or --debug was displayed directly, but now the cursor flashes and the output is printed when the run has been finished. I am now waiting for the verbose and debug output.

Comment: `puppet apply --debug --verbose "C:\temp\puppettest\site.pp"` results in `Debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'`, `Debug: Puppet::Type::File::ProviderPosix: feature posix is missing`, multiple `Debug: Using settings: adding file resource '...':` and `Debug: Failed to load library 'shadow' for feature 'libshadow'`

Comment: And all of that output is printed right at the end, after waiting 7 minutes, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: That's very strange, the delay seems to be all in the process of loading... is the same delay present with other `puppet` commands?  Are you able to get [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on there to check out what the process is doing?

Comment: I have installed process monitor and I have monitored the cmd32 in which puppet is running, but I did not see any changes during a `puppet apply`. `puppet help`, `puppet --version` display the output immediately, while `facter` takes some time to load. I have disabled some network adapters and now the puppet apply took ~60s, but it is still some factors slower than 3.2.4

Comment: There should be a ruby process that fires up when you run those commands, are you seeing that in process monitor?

Comment: Can you tell me if this was a new install of puppet into the evironment(s) in question or an upgrade starting from 2.7.23?

Comment: Would it be possible to get some information on the network adapters you disabled?  In PowerShell, you can use the Get-NetAdapter command to retrieve basic info.  If you'd like to file a ticket at tickets.puppetlabs.com, then we can track this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @Shane Madden. If puppet apply has been finished the number of ruby.exe processes remains the same. If the next puppet apply has been started the number of ruby.exe processes increases and it seems the puppet apply is getting slower again (~45s first run to more than 7 min again)

Comment: @ferventcoder. Puppet 3.5.1 was installed using chocolatey, subsequently this version was removed using windows control panel and remove from the chocolatey's lib folder. Puppet 3.5.1 was downloaded from puppet labs and installed (no difference). Several versions were downloaded from the puppet labs downloadsite and installed in descending version direction.

Comment: Can you run with the `--evaltrace` option on a slowed version to identify the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it was unclear why this issue occurred. The comments could help people debugging similar Puppet issues.